# quiero poner un radio en vez de un select el formulario es python

Tags: javascript, python

aqui esta el form

```
class SolicitudForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Solicitud
    fields = ['convocatoria']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['convocatoria'].label = 'Convocatoria'
    self.fields['convocatoria'].widget.attrs.update({
        'class': 'form-control',
        'data-autocomplete-fields': 'convocatoria',
    })
```

en el html me muestra un select pero lo quiero poner como radio las opciones que me imprime

aqui esta el js

```
        $.fn.select2.defaults.set('language', {
        noResults: function () {
            return 'No Cumples con el Promedio para Solicitar Alguna Beca';
        }
    });
    // Inicializar todos los campos de selección con Select2


    $('select[name="convocatoria"]').select2({
        placeholder: 'Selecciona una opción...',
        allowClear: true
    });

    $('select[name="hermano"]').select2({
        placeholder: 'Selecciona la matrícula del hermano...',
        allowClear: true
    });

    // Obtiene los elementos del formulario
    var convocatoriaField = $('#id_convocatoria');
    var hermanoField = $('#beca_hermano');
    var promedioField = document.getElementById('promedio_field').getAttribute('value');
    const promedioMin = document.getElementsByClassName('promedio_minimo');

    var convocatoriaValues = document.getElementsByTagName("option");

    let selectElement = document.querySelectorAll('[name=convocatoria]');
    let optionNames = [...selectElement[0].options].map(o => o.text);
    let optionValues = [...selectElement[0].options].map(o => o.value);
```

este es el js del form lo mando a llamar desde el html asi solicitud_beca_hermano_form.as_p pero entre llaves dobles y lo que quiero es mostrar las opciones en redio en vez de que me las muestre en un select eso que puse arriba es lo que llevo pero no se me ocurre como sera para ponerlos en radio